# Is it possible to see phased app releases in App Store Connect/iTunes Search API?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I'm able to successfully fetch information regarding the latest version of an app from the iTunes Search API, and information regarding Test Flight versions from App Store Connect.

However, I would also like to be able to get information about any phased releases currently in progress. Is this possible using either of the APIs?

Comment: To my knowledge no, since any new install will give the latest version. The only think the phased release does is not offer the update to everyone at the same time. If the user pull to refresh on the update list they will see the new version and so can by pass the phased release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using App Store Connect:

First, get the version list for your app, using the URL below. The first version in the list will be the newest.

```
https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/{YOUR_APP_ID}/appStoreVersions
```

For each `version`, fetch the resource at the URL in the `relationships` property:

```
version.relationships.appStoreVersionPhasedRelease.links.related
```

The value in `data.attributes.phasedReleaseState` will be `ACTIVE` if the version is currently in a phased release state.

There might be a more direct way of fetching all phased releases directly, but this is how I solved it.